# Save arrays in folders

Tags: iphone, directory

I want to create different folders for each user's account. There are images of user's that are need to be stored in their folder. How can i achieve that i am getting no idea.Can anyone help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Create directory` in your app like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UniqueUserAccount"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
```

---

Now saving `NSMutableArray` refer [read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html) link.

```
folderPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"]; 
[yourArray writeToFile:folderPath atomically:YES];
```

Read array like this:

```
NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:folderPath];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayFromFile);
```

---

**EDIT** : To save image in user account folder from array of images

```
for(int i = 0;i < [arrImages count];i++)
{
  folderPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d",i]]; //here folder Path with Image file
  //Our goal is to create UIImage into NSData if u have image in bundle then take like this:
  NSMutableString *imgPath;
  imgPath=[[NSMutableString  alloc] initWithString: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]; //get bundle path
 [imgPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]]; //get image from bundle to write
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]; //create nsdata of image

 //if u have UIImage 
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([arrImages objectAtIndex:i]) //image reference here to convert into data

 [imageData writeToFile:folderPath atomically:YES]; //write here
}
```

Comment: You may wish to avoid using the `NSDocumentDirectory` directory if the app has enabled iTunes file sharing. Otherwise the user can delete or renamed the account folders through iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, but these are just creating the folders how can i save arrays in it, and then can access them.

Comment: can i ask you another thing in it?

Comment: It is not saving images, what i want is to save the array in to folder that contains images. There is separate code for saving images in array that i have already used to save image in array but that array is not getting saved by this code.

Comment: then don't save array but image in specific user account folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can create directory in your app by:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *newFolder = [(NSString*)[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"uniqueIdentifierForAccount"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newFolder]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't build a path with a format string. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but these are just creating the folders how can i save arrays in it, and then can access them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that rather than needing actual folders, you really just need to store an array connected to a name.  I would advise using the NSUserDefaults.  You can achieve this functionality like this:

```
    //instantiate the NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSArray *userArray;
    NSString *username;

    //Then to store:
    [storage setObject:userArray forKey:username];

    //and to recall:
    userArray = [storage objectForKey:username];
```